# HP Probook 450 G3 Screen Flashing on Low Brightness

Tags: windows-10, drivers, amd-radeon, intel-graphics

I just bought a new HP Probook 450 G3 few days back. After using it for a couple of days, I started noticing screen flashing/flickering when lowering the brightness. This happened both on Windows 7 and Windows 10. I have tried reinstalling and updating Intel HD graphic drivers but that doesn't work. I have also tried installing windows 10 updates but problem still persists. The only way to avoid screen flashing is to keep brightness level high.

The flickering that I see is more like a light bulb flickering. I am not sure if this is a software or hardware issue. Does anyone else face this issue with HP laptops. If so, did you manage to fix it?

Specs:

- Intel Core i7 6500U
- 16GB RAM
- 480GB SSD
- Intel HD Graphics 520
- AMD R7 (2GB)
- Windows 10

Comment: I would ask for full refund, it some sort of hardware issue you cannot fix.

Comment: Does the flickering occur while on mains power or battery or both?

Comment: The flickering occurs on both when brightness is reduced.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Probook 470 G3 i7 6500 with AMD R7 graphics card and run Win 10 Pro. I use a second monitor. When working for an hour or two I also have the screen starting to flash on and off. Eventually the second monitor loses its resolution. I have to go through sleep mode to get it reset. I have read a lot and there seems to be a lot of similar issues.

I have upgraded all drivers and even Bios to no avail.

Although this is not a fix, it is an answer to the question whether anybody have the same issue.

I happen to find a fix as well, after about a month of trial and error. In the BIOS I turned off the TURBO BOOST which seems to allow overclocking. I haven't had a blackout since ...

Comment: You forgot the conclusion : ***The flickering is probably due to inadequate heat management, i.e., overheating of the CPU.***